# SQL queries to another wordpress site

Tags: wpdb, security

I have 2 wordpress sites on the same hosting and the same host/user/ password for the database
I have on the other hand 2 different database and 2 different prefixes
I need, during an action on site1, to go and make requests on site2 (SELECT and after, UPDATE)
I saw that we could do

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");
```

But putting that in site1's functions.php file isn't very secure is it?

How to do this in a clean way and avoid any attempt to hack the database if you access the functions.php file

Answer (score 0):

Putting an important credentials in `functions.php` is not a good idea. The better way is you can utilize WP REST API from your second site to handle GET and POST method for the data and using global `$wpdb` variable inside the code.

You can either create a custom endpoint for that by making a custom plugin or insert the code into `functions.php`. You may need to configure the `permission_callback` parameter for the API endpoint whether it is being used internally or publicly.

Read more on [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

Comment: I succeeded by adding the information in the wp-config file (eg SECOND_USER_DB etc) that's fine too isn't it?